# Django - User Profile field won't change after form submit

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to have a part of my user profile change after my form is submitted. The user profile has a discipline field, and I want the user to be able to modify it. When I click submit now, nothing changes.

I am a beginner at Django, so I am sure this is a minor fix. I've been trying to get this to work the past few days.

views.py

```
@login_required
def change_discipline(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #     #create a form instance and populate it with data from the request
        form = DisciplineChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
             #process data in form.clean_data
            discipline = Discipline(name=form.cleaned_data['discipline'])
            request.user.profile.primaryDiscipline = discipline
            request.user.save()
            request.user.profile.save()
            return render_to_response('changediscipline.html', { 'form': form }, context)
else:
    form = DisciplineChoiceForm(request.POST)

return render_to_response('changediscipline.html', {'form': form}, context )
```

models.py 
user profile

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #this line is required. Links MyUser to a User Model
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name ="profile")
#Additional Attributes we wish to include
date_of_birth = models.FloatField(blank=False)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank = True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank = True)
state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank = True)
zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank = True)
admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank = True)
mentor = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank = True)
mentee = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank = True)
# profilepicture = models.ImageField()
#is_staff = True
tagline = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank = True, default="Let's do this!")
interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, related_name="interest", symmetrical = False)
primaryDiscipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, default=False, blank = True)
addtlDisciplines = models.ManyToManyField(Discipline, related_name="disciplines", symmetrical=False)
```

html

```
<div class = "container">
  <h1>Choose a Discipline in {{interest}}</h1>
  <form action="{% url 'myapp:change_discipline'  %}" method="POST" id="discipline-select">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
    <!-- {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="id_interest" name="discipline">
      <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
      {% for d in disciplines %}
      <option value={{d.id}}>{{d.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Load Disciplines"/>
  </form> -->
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class DisciplineChoiceForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, interest, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DisciplineChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['discipline'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [(o.id, str(o)) for o in Discipline.objects.all()])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok should have read better. The first problem:

```
# this creates an unsaved Discipline instance
discipline = Discipline(name=form.cleaned_data['discipline'])
# and assign it to request.user.profile
request.user.profile.primaryDiscipline = discipline
```

Since your `Profile.primary_discipline` allows nulls, the call to `request.user.profile.save()` doesn't raise an IntegrityError, so nothing happens indeed.

Now you didn't post your `DisciplineChoiceForm` so we don't know what `form.cleaned_data['discipline']` points to, but that's obviously not going to work - what you want is to get the actual (saved) `Discipline` instance.

If your form's `discipline` field is a `forms.ChoiceField` and has `(id, name)` tuples as choices, then `form.cleaned_data['discipline']` will yield the discipline id, and you'll get the correct `Discipline` instance with `Discipline.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['discipline'])`:

```
discipline = Discipline.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['discipline'])
request.user.profile.primaryDiscipline = discipline
request.user.profile.save()
```

but you might be better using a [`forms.ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead which will directly return the selected `Discipline` instance in which case you can simplify your code to:

```
discipline = form.cleaned_data['discipline']
request.user.profile.primaryDiscipline = discipline
request.user.profile.save()
```

Comment: `profile =  request.user.profile;
        profile.primaryDiscipline = discipline` is the same as `request.user.profile.primaryDiscipline = discipline; request.user.profile.save`.

Comment: @bad_keypoints you're totally right in this case, my bad . And the problem was elsewhere anyway, cf my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah. Now your last snippet of code is what the OP should do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed it to ModelChoiceField as well. It's a lot prettier now.